# point my localhost website to a public domain name

Tags: apache, dns, server, wampserver, domain-name

I have just set up a **WAMPserver2.5** localhost on my computer. I have everything running properly (I can execute PHP, MYSQL, etc...) and I forwarded port 80 to my ip adress 192.168.1.4 (I can get my localhost page from my public ip) am now wondering **how I would point my public ip to a domain name** that could be accessed outside of my network.
 Is this possible? If so, how would I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: When you say _I can get my localhost page from my public ip_ , do you mean that you can see the WAMPServer homepage when you use your purchased domain name when run from an external location?

Comment: yes, but my problem that my public ip change every day .

Comment: Then you are going to have to consider the Dynamic DNS approach, as those provide a little app you run on the PC that updates your external IP to the Dynamic DNS every time it changes.

Comment: thnks!, can you give me a name of this app ?

Comment: See @ByteHamster answer, he has already mentioned that option. I use DYNDNS.COM but you have to pay for their dyndns access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [No-IP](https://www.noip.com) to do that. They offer free subdomains but you can also purchase an own domain.

Comment: I've already bought a domain name but problem that I cant point it to my ip adress, on the main domain control I can add nameservers and Host Records. I do not know how or what should I do.

Comment: If your hosting provider does not support dynamic host redirects, it will be hard. You could redirect your domain to the no-ip domain using a htaccess file. Users will not notice that they are redirected.

Comment: thnks for the reply but, how can I check that my hosting provider support dynamic host redirects or not ?

Comment: Usually, providers do not offer that. (If so, they will have it somewhere in the domain control). It requires a program on your PC that tells the server your current IP every few minutes.